# C# DataTable.WriteXml without specific column

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

I have a DataTable that looks like this:

`Count | Email | Link | Action` (in this column is a Button that deletes a selected row)

And i would like to save this to XML, but i don't want to save an Action column. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a copy of database, delete column and then create xml.

Like this

```
DataSet ori_ds = //Populate Dataset

DataSet cop_ds = ori_ds.Copy();

cop_ds.Columns.Remove("Action");

string str = cop_ds.GetXml();
```